# pandas df locate keep only first item

Tags: python, pandas

i want to get the value of another column based on a value in a certain column, in the same row.

example:

for business id = '123', i want to retrieve the business_name

df:

```
biz_id  biz_name
123      chew
456      bite
123      chew
```

code:

```
df['biz_name'].loc[df['biz_id'] == 123]
```

returns me:

```
chew
chew
```

how do i get just 1 value of `'chew'` in string format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) or [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) for select first value of `Series`:

```
print (df.loc[df['biz_id'] == 123, 'biz_name'].iloc[0])
chew
```

Or:

```
print (df.loc[df['biz_id'] == 123, 'biz_name'].iat[0])
chew
```

With `query`:

```
print (df.query('biz_id == 123')['biz_name'].iloc[0])
chew
```

Or select first value in `list` or `numpy array`:

```
print (df.loc[df['biz_id'] == 123, 'biz_name'].tolist()[0])
chew

print (df.loc[df['biz_id'] == 123, 'biz_name'].values[0])
chew
```

**Timings**:

```
In [18]: %timeit (df.loc[df['biz_id'] == 123, 'biz_name'].iloc[0])
1000 loops, best of 3: 399 µs per loop

In [19]: %timeit (df.loc[df['biz_id'] == 123, 'biz_name'].iat[0])
The slowest run took 4.16 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 391 µs per loop

In [20]: %timeit (df.query('biz_id == 123')['biz_name'].iloc[0])
The slowest run took 4.39 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.75 ms per loop

In [21]: %timeit (df.loc[df['biz_id'] == 123, 'biz_name'].tolist()[0])
The slowest run took 4.18 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 384 µs per loop

In [22]: %timeit (df.loc[df['biz_id'] == 123, 'biz_name'].values[0])
The slowest run took 5.32 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 370 µs per loop

In [23]: %timeit (df.loc[df.biz_id.eq(123).idxmax(), 'biz_name'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 517 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `idxmax` to grab index of first maximal value

```
df.loc[df.biz_id.eq(123).idxmax(), 'biz_name']

'chew'
```